# Why is it so hard to print a web page properly?

Tags: html, printing-web-page

I printed a page from a bank web site. Aside from the page with my data, I got five other pages with just a logo, just a header, just a footer, etc. It's sort of a joke in my household that you can't print a web page without getting a useless wasted page too.

So, why is it so hard? Are we blaming the web page designers, the browsers, or who? I would have thought this would be a mature technology by now and suffer from these idiotic little foibles.

I especially don't understand why printing from a "print preview" gives you something different from what you preview.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't an appropriate place to ask this question. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Isnt this a programmers matter? I could agree that the question is too broad however. @MikeAtlas

Comment: @AndersLindén No, it isn't. The original question is like asking an auto-mechanic why traffic jams happen.

Comment: I believe some cars have software to reduce traffic jams.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the programming perspective on this - it's hard, because screen size and resolution is different from the size and resolution of the printed page. Therefore most pages will not automatically print well - it's up to the web designer add CSS that's specific to printed output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print-only.css" />
```

Most web designers are too lazy to do this unless there's a specific reason to print their page, so most pages don't print well.

Comment: You can dramatically resize webpages and they never look as bad as when they are printed.  Why can't there at least be an option to print (pixel-for-pixel, if necessary) the literal thing I'm looking at with my browser.  Why force me to screen-shot it?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets):

> Two of the most common problems with
>   printing occur when positioning other
>   than static is used (e.g. position:
>   absolute) or when there are floats.

Developers have the choice of making a special version of a given page so that it can be printed the right way. This can be achieved using the media type "print" with CSS.

See these pages for further reference:

[Print Stylesheets](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets)

[CSS Media Types](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

At best, web pages are designed to flow and scroll on various screen sizes.  At worst, they only work on a single size screen.  Printed pages obviously have pagination, not scrolling, and they use a fixed size.

As Leniel says, CSS [media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) provide a suitable mechanism to provide different styles on a printed page, but from my experience not many sites use it.